# Images stored in SharePoint Online not showing

Tags: sharepoint, yammer

Recently we have noticed that the images stored in SharePoint online are not showing. Debugging the issue to ensure it is not on our side, we have noticed that Yammer refuses to load images because of the following directive:

```
"img-src 'self' data: *.assets-yammer.com *.msocdn.com *.microsoft.com *.microsoftonline.com *.office.com *.office365.com".
```

*.sharepoint.com is not there. Is this intentional (supposedly internal DNS at their side might make rerouting for the *.microsoftonline.com)?